# VBA - How to determine the number of legend entries shown

Tags: vba, powerpoint, legend

I've looked all over for the answer to this and I am completely stumped. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Look at this example:
[image: example picture]

As you can see, there are 20 `.Series` in the `.Chart`, but only 15 are visible in the `.Legend`.
I want to use VBA to adjust the `.Legend` size and/or reduce the `.Legend` font size until all 20 `.Series` are shown in the `.Legend`.

But I have no idea how to determine the number of `.LegendEntries` *shown* in the `.Legend`.

`.Legend.LegendEntries.Count` gives me "20" as a result.

I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 1):

Using this code on your example (your results may vary) you can identify which legend entries are not visible.  It calculates the difference between the legend's window and the legend entry's top.  A negative should indicate it is not visible

```
        Dim c As Chart, nLegH As Single
        Set c = ActiveChart
        With c.Legend
                nLegH = .Top + .Height
                Debug.Print nLegH
                For x = 1 To 20
                        Debug.Print .LegendEntries(x).Top, nLegH - .LegendEntries(x).Top
                Next x
        End With
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I had not thought of that at all. It does not seem as straight-forward as that though. Looking through the positions of the entries that are not shown makes little sense to me.

I thought adding in the same check but for the right hand side of the legend as well would do the trick, but it seems the entries can just about be in the legend with their edges and that messes up the comparison. 

This is very close to a solution, thank you again!

Comment: Delving further into this, I'm beginning to think that the entries not shown are simply invisible. There are cases where the entries not show are clearly positioned within the legend. Infact, they are often stacked ontop eachother at the same position as Series 1... To my mind this means they should have a '.Visible' boolean or something...